# Eclipse 4.4.1 - BIRT report preview error - Failed to initialize emitter - Access is denied

Tags: birt, birt-emitter

I trying to debug a simple report , but receiving this exception.

```html
12:05:54 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.vm.ReportVMServer start
INFO: [Server] client accepted
פבר 20, 2015 12:05:54 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.vm.ReportVMServer$1 run
INFO: [Server] enter request dispatching
פבר 20, 2015 12:05:54 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher configEngine
INFO: User class path received: 
פבר 20, 2015 12:05:54 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask handleFatalExceptions
SEVERE: An error happened while running the report. Cause:
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Failed to initialize emitter.
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.EmitterUtil.getOuputStream(EmitterUtil.java:82)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.html.HTMLReportEmitter.initialize(HTMLReportEmitter.java:358)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.initializeContentEmitter(EngineTask.java:2320)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:118)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.createReport(ReportLauncher.java:620)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.renderReport(ReportLauncher.java:566)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.run(ReportLauncher.java:480)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.main(ReportLauncher.java:124)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.ReportDebugger.start(ReportDebugger.java:39)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \reportForGenerateFromEngine.rptdesign.html (Access is denied)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.EmitterUtil.getOuputStream(EmitterUtil.java:77)
 ... 22 more

פבר 20, 2015 12:05:54 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher renderReport
SEVERE: Engine exception
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Failed to initialize emitter.
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.EmitterUtil.getOuputStream(EmitterUtil.java:82)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.html.HTMLReportEmitter.initialize(HTMLReportEmitter.java:358)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.initializeContentEmitter(EngineTask.java:2320)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:118)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.createReport(ReportLauncher.java:620)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.renderReport(ReportLauncher.java:566)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.run(ReportLauncher.java:480)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.main(ReportLauncher.java:124)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.ReportDebugger.start(ReportDebugger.java:39)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \reportForGenerateFromEngine.rptdesign.html (Access is denied)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.EmitterUtil.getOuputStream(EmitterUtil.java:77)
 ... 22 more

פבר 20, 2015 12:05:54 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.vm.ReportVMServer$1 run
WARNING: [Server] client disconnected
```

I use windows 7 professional.
I tried to change the default browser or enter this lines to the eclipse.ini file but it's not helped.

Hope for your help..

Answer (score 5):

Switch to the Debug perspective, that gives you access to the full "Run" menu. Open "Debug configurations...", that should give you access to an item under "Report" which is you debug configuration. Inside this item, change the "Temp folder" location to something you trust. That should solve it.

Comment: This is the solution to the problem, it worked. @hcohen you should accept this as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

From your error

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   \reportForGenerateFromEngine.rptdesign.html (Access is denied)"

it is a file system issue. If you are previewing in BIRT Designer, verify that your save location is writable and optionally try running BIRT Designer as admin (just to check). Otherwise check that you have permission to read and write with whatever method you are using to generate this report.

Comment: If this location is user configurable, then tell were. The OP said how he was generating the report.